# How to keep the release branch updated?

Tags: git, branch

I use branch `master` for development and `release` for release related stuff. Ideally I'd like them to look like this before every release:

```
                      v release
              o - o - o 
             /
o - o - o - o
            ^ master
```

This can be achieved by rebasing release onto `master`, however then pushing `release` to origin becomes problematic. How to best handle this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to handle this situation would be to force push the `release` branch to the remote, via:

```
git checkout release
git push --force origin release
```

As you probably suspect, this becomes problematical because it rewrites the history of the public `release` branch, which means that anyone else who then pulls this branch might get unexpected results.

However, let us take a closer look at the meaning of the `release` branch.  Typically, a release branch would come into existence because a bunch of features are needed for a milestone in your software product.  After a release is finished, the corresponding branch could be frozen and further commits blocked.  If fixes are needed for the release, let them go into a new branch.

To get to the punchline, you would be fairly safe in rebasing the `release` branch on `master` and force pushing if few people, or even no one, *needed* to pull this branch again.  And this point in time would be precisely when the release goes out, at which point all activity on your `release` branch should cease.

So, my advice would be to force push your `release` branch at the end of the cycle.

Comment: I removed acceptation and gave +1 instead, since I feel now that it's not a perfect solution and after using rebases I personally decided to use merges instead. Mostly because I also tag every commit I built from and then the history starts to look very unnatural

Comment: @Dunno Actually merging makes the history look unnatural because it erases it.  Rebasing preserves history because it maintains the commits which were made.  But the choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

As fireflieslive mentioned, you should use merge instead of rebase. That way, your history will look like:

```
                      v release(1)        v release(2) 
              o - o - o  -------  o - o - o 
             /                   /
o - o - o - o - o - o - o - o - o
            ^ master(1)         ^ master(2)
```

where I have now depicted two different releases (and the status of the master at the time of that release).

Concretely, whenever you want to release you do

```
git checkout release
git merge master
<edit release related stuff and commit>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `merge` instead of `rebase`

> The golden rule of git rebase is to never use it on public branches

[atlassian git tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/conceptual-overview)